# Cross Site Collection Workflows

Tags: 2007, workflow

Is it possible to create custom workflows which can update list/libraries across a site collection (under same web app)?

Appreciate any help/guidance.

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" with SharePoint 2007 workflows is impersonation, workflows run under initator account (user who started the workflow). The workaround this the easiest way is to create a web service that is performing the tasks the you need, you simply need to invoke this web service from your custom activity/code.

You web service can use regular SharePoint API to perform tasks as necessary. SPSite, SPWeb etc.. will do just fine.

Comment: The current application design does not permit to host any web service that can perform the task. It needs to be the WF that can persist the state across site collection.

Comment: What about permissions? Same user have cross site collection permissions? E.g Can a user that started a workflow make modification in different Site Collection?

Comment: The approver group lies in the second site collection and the user who started the workflow in the first site collection.

Comment: I lost you... you can try to email me at firstname.lastname@gmail.com and maybe explain in more details...